# What does "cable" mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english

I came across the word "cable" very often in http://www.guardian.co.uk.

Like:

- [WikiLeaks cables: Drive to tackle Islamists made 'little progress'](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2010/dec/13/wikileaks-cables-uk-muslim-communities)
- [US embassy cables: How the Guardian protects sources](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/video/2010/dec/07/us-embassy-cables-guardian-sources-video)
- [WikiLeaks embassy cables: the key points at a glance](http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/2010/nov/29/wikileaks-embassy-cables-key-points)

I know what a cable is, but what does "cable" here mean?

Comment: You will sometimes encounter things like "cabled in" or "wired in" in older work; this is related.

Comment: It has been amusing me how all the Wikileaks coverage has been about leaked "cables". I wonder why the media hasn't been calling them leaked emails?

Comment: This question was posted in 2010, when this site did not have a "show research" requirement. It makes no sense to me to retroactively impose such a requirement on such an ancient question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The word "cable" has its origins in the days of the telegraph. Messages sent internationally via undersea cables were known as "cablegrams" or "cables", for short. Another interesting point to note is a cable (the means of transmission) is insulated and protected from external elements, distinguishing it from an ordinary wire, which is just bare metal. In the early twentieth century, governments and agencies communicated via cablegram and the name has since stuck. Another reason I would suggest for this enduring usage, even with the advent of modern telecommunications, is the security and encryption involved in relaying these messages. The messages are sent via a secure link and chances are that the signal even travels through an undersea fiber optic cable before reaching its destination!

Comment: RE: secure link: apparently, not secure enough :)

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: Apparently. On second thoughts, though, I would say the link was perfectly secure, but someone with access "leaked" them. Should this be regarded as a security issue or one of treasonable proportion?

Comment: one man's treason is another man's patriotism.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the day, "cable" was used to describe communications sent abroad. In the case of Guardian, it seems to refer to news from overseas.

Comment: NB The newspaper is "The Guardian" (with a definite article), despite what its domain name (and a lot of the website) might lead you to believe :)

Answer (score 0):

"Cable" in this context, means "cablegram." It refers to a report sent via a cable, not to the cable itself.

Answer (score -1):

I believe "cable" is another word for "transmission," similar to the noun "wire"

Think Telegrams